# JavaScript console writing task with callbacks/ closures?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript task where I need to print to the console different instructions after a certain amount of time has passed. The task is to make and serve sandwiches. A sandwich takes 1 minute to make, and 30 seconds to serve.

The function needs to take the number of sandwiches that are requested and print in an order like "Make Sandwich 1, Serve Sandwich 1, Make Sandwich 2, Serve Sandwich 2" etc

This is what I have so far, but it's not working correctly and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
function makeSandwich(num, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    console.log("Make Sandwich " + i);
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(i);
    }, 6000);
  }
}

function serveSandwich(num) {
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Serve sandwich " + num);
  }, 3000);
}

makeSandwich(2, serveSandwich); //this does make, make, serve, serve
```

Comment: what do you mean? make, make, serve, serve is exactly expected behavior if we consider that sandwiches should be made at the same time and not consequently

Comment: haha yes that would be the ideal real life situation! but for my task, I'm trying to understand how I can call a function multiple times, wait for it to complete and then run again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a little `delay` function using a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to execute the food order.

```js
// Takes a number in milliseconds
function delay(n) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), n);
  });
}

// Now iterate, log the result,
// and delay for `n` milliseconds
async function makeOrder(num) {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    console.log(`Make sandwich ${i + 1}`);
    await delay(2000);
    console.log(`Serve sandwich ${i + 1}`);
    await delay(1000);
  }
}

makeOrder(2);
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! This works how I require and is a little easier for me to understand than the callbacks solution offered above :)

Comment: Yeah, async/await removes the need for callback hell :) @smose

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `setTimeout` callbacks are asynchronous, so when you use it, the rest of the code keeps running.

When you call `makeSandwich`, this is what happens:

- First loop

  - log to console: "Make sandwich 0"
  - start `setTimeout` timer (A), the passed function will run in 6 seconds
  - end loop
- Second loop

  - log to console: "Make sandwich 1"
  - start second `setTimeout` timer (B)
  - end loop
- First timer (A) completes

  - callback(0) is called
  - start `setTimeout` timer (C) for serving sandwich 1
- Second timer (B) competes

  - callback(1) is called
  - start `setTimeout` timer (D) for serving sandwich 2
- Third timer (C) completes

  - log to console: "Serve sandwich 0"
- Fourth timer (D) completes

  - log to console: "Serve sandwich 1"

If you want the functions to be run sequentially, you can use recursive callbacks.

```js
// Make the sandwiches one by one, waiting each to complete before working on the next one
function makeSandwich(num, callback, i = 1) {
  console.log("Make Sandwich " + i);
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Pass a callback to the callback that will trigger when serving is complete
    callback(i, () => {
      // If there are still sandwiches left to make, start the next one
      if (i < num) {
        // This is the recusive part, the function calls itself to trigger the next loop 
        makeSandwich(num, callback, ++i);
      }
    });
  }, 6000);
}

function serveSandwich(num, callback) {
  console.log("Serve sandwich " + num);
  // This callback will let us know when serving is complete
  setTimeout(() => callback(), 3000);
}

makeSandwich(2, serveSandwich);
```

Comment: This does what I need it to, thank you so much! I think it will take me a while to understand properly how it works as I haven't done much with callbacks before but can definitely work with this :) I also haven't seen this approach instead of using a for loop. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer to explain what your code does. Hopefully, that will help you understand the difference. @Andy's answer is a bit neater if you can use newer JavaScript features.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you ment?

```
function makeSandwichNew(num, callback) {
    if (num==0) console.log('Order \'Making\' Ready')
    else
    {
      console.log("Make Sandwich " + num);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sandwitch ' + num + ' ready')
        makeSandwichNew(num-1, callback)
        callback(num);
      }, 6000);
    }
}
```

Comment: not quite what I'm looking for, but thank you for your help! :)

Comment: It is/does the same as the other answer (except countdown in stead of normal county)